# nz-popover - nzPopoverPlacement, target another element for centering

Tags: ng-zorro-antd

I was wondering if there was a way to get the nz-popover to center on another element.

I basically have a text input followed by two buttons in a div, I would like to center the popover on the div rather than on the button that triggers it.

I found that i could add the popover to the actual div and then use the nzVisible to trigger it but then i loose the ability to close the popup when the user leaves the area (prob when they hover over the mask or click it). I tried many ways to close it once the popover looses focus etc but that would cause the popover to close if the popover contains a menu or datepicker (when they are used).

Anyone got any ideas? (i used to use angular material and i believe they had something similar (think it was called target or something).

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is interested in this, we have submitted a [PR](https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/pull/4849) to provide this feature. You would be able to use this in 9.x (and future) versions.